# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate - time tracking window missing

Tags: intellij-idea, time-tracking

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1 (Build #IU-171.3780.107, built on March 22, 2017) on Linux.

According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/time-tracking-tool-window.html) there should be a Time Management tool window available in **Tools** >  **Tool Windows**  > **Time Tracking**

However, I'm not seeing this option in the menu. The "task management" and "time tracking" plugins are installed and Time Tracking is enabled.
Does anyone know why the window is missing? I'd like to be able to report my time spent on tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've enabled this feature:

[image: time tracking]

Comment: Thank you! One would think that JetBrains would actually put this in the documentation. I never even thought of looking through the settings.